# Removing duplicate entries from an array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this when I use var_dump:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=> array(2) { 
    [0]=> string(1) "1"
    ["userID"]=> string(1) "1" 
  }
  [1]=> array(2) {
    [0]=> string(1) "2" 
    ["userID"]=> string(1) "2"
  }
  [2]=> array(2) { 
    [0]=> string(1) "1"
    ["userID"]=> string(1) "1"
  } 
  [3]=> array(2) {
    [0]=> string(1) "1"
    ["userID"]=> string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

That is `1,2,1,1`

I tried using `array_unique($arr)` but on this particular array, instead of turning it into `1,2`, it just turns the array into `1`.

It should work, but I'm not sure why it doesn't.

Comment: What is the resultant array that you are looking for? "turning [the array] into `1,2`" doesn't make  much sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to guess that all you care about is knowing which userIDs exist in the result set. Therefore, I will flatten the array first. After doing so, I can apply `array_unique` to obtain only the unique values. As others have stated, `array_unique` is not designed to work with multidimensional arrays.

```
$flattened = array_map(
  function($e) { return $e['userID']; },
  $array
);
$unique = array_unique($flattened);
```

If you like `foreach` loops, then it would look like this.

```
$flattened = array();
foreach ($array as $v) {
    $flattened[] = $v['userId'];
}
$unique = array_unique($flattened);
```

There is also an alternative to finding unique elements which offers a performance boost over `array_unique` -- O(n) time complexity versus O(nlogn). That is,  `array_unique($array)` is equivalent to `array_keys(array_flip($array))`.

Answer (score 4):

array_unique only removes elements that are equal by their string value. That is not the case for sub-arrays.

You will need to iterate over the array manually (after sorting with a user function) and unset the doubles. Not pretty, sorry.

Comment: I don't think he *needs* to, but it is an option.

Answer (score 2):

A kind of quick and dirty method might be to iterate over all elements, serialize the values and use these as keys in a new array that contains their values as well then use `array_values()` on that array like this:

```
<?php
function array_unique_recursive(array $a) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($a as $item)
        $result[serialize($item)] = $item;
    return array_values($result);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arr = array(
               array ( 0=>"1",
                        userID=>"1"),
                array ( 0=>"2",
                        userID=>"2"),
        array ( 0=>"1",
                        userID=>"1"),
        array ( 0=>"1",
                        userID=>"1"));

    $arr_unique=array_unique($arr);
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($arr_unique);
    echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using sort regular filter ...
`<?php 
$arr = array_unique($arr, SORT_REGULAR);
?>`